# variables in SQL update

Tags: php, sql

Just building up this update script which updates the colour in the database to be used in the styling of a Div. I know this is open to SQLInjection, but for the minute its an internal site only, and a concept.

```
  <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('HOST', 'USER', 'PASSWORD','DATABASE');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    $user = $_GET['user'];
    $colour = $_GET['colour'];

    $sql= " UPDATE phoneavail
    SET Colour = '$colour' WHERE Name = '$user'"

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }

    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

The problem is that it just wont run correctly, I have tried different queries with no success.
The colour variable is being pulled from the URL; I tested it by Echo'ing the $colour variable.

A Sample of the URL: `http://localhost/test/php/phone/busy-demo.php?colour=green&user=Jack`

The table structure is fairly simple:

Columns     |   Name   |   Colour  |

sample data |  Jack    |   red     |

Comment: define: `it just won't run correctly`

Comment: Also, remove the `header()` for now and do `echo $sql` and see if you can run that query manually.

Comment: after you click the link for the PHP page it results in a blank screen with a similar URL to the example, no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semicolon is missing in the update query.

```
$sql= " UPDATE phoneavail SET Colour = '$colour'";
```

Comment: I really need to start proof reading, this is the correct answer, I will mark it when I can in 8 minutes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$user = $_GET['user'];
$colour = $_GET['colour'];

$sql= " UPDATE phoneavail SET Colour = '$colour' WHERE Name = '$user'"

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_close($con);
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

and close connection before redirecting.